# cannot import name patterns

Tags: python, django

Before I wrote in `urls.py`, my code... everything worked perfectly. Now I have problems - can't go to my site. "cannot import name patterns"

My `urls.py` is:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
```

They said what error is somewhere here.

Comment: Can you please show us the full error and trace?

Comment: I had the same problem while following the "write your first django app" guide. When I moved the url patters from the main urls.py to polls.urls.py. The problem solved after I changed "from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url" with "from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
"

Comment: I had the same issue when deploying to my staging server. Problem went away went I upgraded from django 1.3.1 to 1.4 by running sudo pip install --upgrade django

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You don't need those imports. The only thing you need in your urls.py (to start) is:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

# This two if you want to enable the Django Admin: (recommended)
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    # ... your url patterns
)
```

**NOTE:** This solution was intended for Django <1.6. This was actually the code generated by Django itself. For newer version, see Jacob Hume's answer.

Comment: import * is considered a bad practice

Comment: from django.conf.urls.defaults import * is removed from djnago1.6

Comment: Every time you `import *` a kitten dies

Comment: If he couldn't import patterns explicitly, using `*` won't work either...

Comment: No more a correct answer and an anti pattern (of import * ) is being promoted. Please update answer accordingly

Answer (score 162):

As of Django 1.10, the `patterns` module has been removed (it had been deprecated since 1.8).

Luckily, it should be a simple edit to remove the offending code, since the `urlpatterns` [should now be stored in a plain-old list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#example):

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    # ... your url patterns
]
```

Comment: but how can i append the `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` to the urlpatterns

Comment: How to add media url: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: For better documentation and rationale on this change in Django 1.8, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.8/#django-conf-urls-patterns

Comment: And you must remove the blank URL `''` at the first position of `urlpatterns`, otherwise you'll get a Regex AttributeError. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34853531/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-regex-django-1-9#35875147

Answer (score 21):

Yes:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import ... # is for django 1.3
from django.conf.urls  import ...         # is for django 1.4
```

I met this problem too.

Answer (score 12):

patterns module is not supported.. mine worked with this.

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    # ... your url patterns
]
```

Answer (score 6):

This is the code which worked for me. My django version is **1.10.4 final**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'blog.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 4):

Pattern module in not available from django 1.8. So you need to remove pattern from your import and do something similar to the following:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [                 
    # here we are not using pattern module like in previous django versions
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I Resolved it by cloning my project directly into Eclipse from GIT,

Initially I was cloning it at specific location on file system then importing it as existing project into Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using outdated version of django..
Simply update django and try again..
Following command will update your django version..

`pip install --upgrade django`

Comment: If only it were that simple

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```