# Django static files on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-staticfiles, staticfilehandler

I deployed a django app to heroku, using "git push heroku master" which worked absolutely fine.

I then created a second app on the same git using "heroku create second-app -r staging'

and pushed using: git push staging master

when I open second-app, none of the static files are picked up or loaded (ie no css, js, or images work)

This is extremely confusing - please help!

my settings file is below

```
import os
import platform
import dj_database_url

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

# This should work for any deployment
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..'))

ADMINS = (
    ('me', 'me@gmailcom'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS
# LOCAL SETTINGS
if platform.system() in ['Windows', 'Darwin']:
    #EV = 'LOCAL'
    DATABASES = {
             'default': {
                 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
                 'NAME': BASE_DIR + '//db//db.sqlite3',
                 'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
                 'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
                 'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
                 'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
             }
    }
    # Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

    CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': 'unique-snowflake',
        'TIMEOUT': 86400,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'MAX_ENTRIES': 10000
            },
        }
    }

# HEROKU SETTINGS
else:
    #EV = 'HEROKU'
    # DEBUG = False
    DATABASES = {}
    DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()

    # Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

    # Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
    # Allow all host headers
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

    # Todo: ammar - update to Memcached
    CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': 'unique-snowflake',
        'TIMEOUT': 86400,
        'OPTIONS': {'MAX_ENTRIES': 10000},
        }
    }

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-gb'

SITE_ID = 1

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False

MEDIA_ROOT = ''

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = ()

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)


SECRET_KEY = '***'

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',

)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'sm.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'sm.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mytemplates')
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'smcore',
    'south',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
)



LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}

LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/getStarted/'
LOGOUT_URL = '/do_logout/'

# e-mail server
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '***@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST= 'smtp.gmail.com'
# EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '***'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = '***@gmail.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = '***@gmail.com'
```

Update

I took a copy of the code and redeployed, which worked with the following updates to the settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'smcore','static')),
)


STATICFILES_FINDERS = (

    #'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

I then branched my code (so I have master and staging) and synced new heroku remote into my staging branch. I then did a git push staging staging:master and it did a full upload; which has once again got me back to the same place... help!!!

Comment: I also had the same problem with the second app. When I deleted the first and re-committed, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Eventually solved this using the below in my urls file - from this question: [Heroku - Handling static files in Django app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047054/heroku-handling-static-files-in-django-app)

```
from <app> import settings
urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    )
```

Comment: Note that `patterns` has now been removed from Django so you should just append additional routes to your existing list per this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074955/cannot-import-name-patterns

Comment: do I need to add this if there is no images in my project?

Answer (score 9):

I have been dealing with the same problem too. I tried not to use the solution recommended by David since it seems to be used only in development (and not production) (See: [Heroku static files not loading, Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28961177/heroku-static-files-not-loading-django))

And here are the 2 things that I changed in my code.

(I'm using Django 1.7)

1) settings.py

I add these lines to the setting files

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
    # Add to this list all the locations containing your static files 
)
```

STATIC_ROOT: this tells Django where to (a) put the static files when you run "python manage.py collectstatic" and (b) find the static files when you run the application

TEMPLATE_DIRS: this tells Django where to look for your static files when it search for statics files when you run "python manage.py collectstatic"

2) wsgi.py

Originally my file was:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "xxxx.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And I changed it to:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "xxxx.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Read here for more information on whitenoise: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#whitenoise

---

Also, remember to install whitenoise:
    pip install whitenoise==2.0.6

Before deploying the project, run:
    python manage.py collectstatic

This will create a folder indicated by STATIC_ROOT (declared in your settings.py), containing all your static files.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that it's because you're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting.

In comparison, my settings.py is something like:

```
# Static asset configuration
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../myapp/static')
```

You should set the STATICFILES_DIRS too (note that my conf for this var is probably not the same than yours)

Then, push your code and try again.
If it still doesn't work, you can use this to debug :
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#debugging

Comment: But the exact same settings file works for the old app - I just don't understand why there would be a difference?

Comment: It's hard to tell, but when it's possible, I prefer explicit things rather than "it works but I don't know why"...After having strange behaviours I decided to set all variables to prevent this kind of things. As you're using PaaS, you can't be sure about what it's done on the server side, so you should follow carefully guidances. in the Heroku Django guide examples, the STATIC_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIRS variables are set. You should try to follow this.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and got this in the standard heroku push output - yet no difference:
-----> Collecting static files
       245 static files copied.

Comment: I also tried a copy of exactly the same code which worked first time around in a different directory, different git and new app but it still failed.... any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Since Django 1.3 you've been able to do the following

```py
# only showing relevant imports
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',

    # your urls go here
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 2):

For Django 2.1.7, I did the following changes in order to work:

1. Added `whitenoise` to requirements.txt in addition to `gunicorn`
2. Project `settings.py` should have the following:

   A) static settings:

   ```
   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

   STATICFILES_DIRS = [
       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), 
   ]
   ```

   B) Add `whitenoise` to middleware:

   ```
   MIDDLEWARE = [
      .....
      'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
   ]
   ```

Finally commit and push your changes then deploy your app peacefully.