# Unable to perform collectstatic

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I am new to django ! When I use the command `python manage.py collectstatic` I get this error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path
```

But I can successfully run the server .

My static files declarations are :

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (

    ('assets', os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, '../static')),
)
```

and debug is set to true

```
DEBUG = True
```

How can I fix this? Else am missing any installation packages ?

Comment: heroku http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141315/django-static-files-on-heroku

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Try this,

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
```

Look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT

Comment: Thanks :) Works ! Before i was using this application with static root as empty . But it worked ! What could be the problem now ?

Comment: You need define the static folder.So all static files are collected in that folder. `You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path`

Answer (score 10):

You must have to give path in STATIC_ROOT  in settings.py where all your static files are collected as for example:-

```
STATIC_ROOT = "app-root/repo/wsgi/static"

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('assets', 'app-root/repo/wsgi/openshift/static'),

    )
```

Answer (score 3):

you can create 'static' folder in any subfolder and have required files in it.
In settings.py add the following lines of code:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

After running 
`python manage.py collectstatic`
a new static folder will be created in your parent App folder

Answer (score 2):

well had this error as well. I fixed:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
if DEBUG:
   STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
   ]
else:
   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to put `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` above the `STATICFILES_DIRS` declaration.

Comment: I had to delete STATICFILES_DIRS and then it worked...

Answer (score 1):

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assest')
STATICFILES_DIR = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: There is a typo: "assets"

Answer (score 0):

```
STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/YourSiteFolder/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#deployment

Answer (score 0):

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

This works for me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to load static files rather than admin panel files or getting errors while loading webpage static files like CSS js etc

I suggest you **change the folder name** of '**static**' to '**staticfiles**'

and then add this code in your settings.py

**STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
)**

then after run python **manage.py collectstatic**

Then the problem will be fixed

[image]