# Django server not making changes to CSS

Tags: python, css, django, django-staticfiles

I'm pretty new to Django. I started an app, made template and static directories, add them to the project settings and ran the server by following [this tutorial](https://djangoforbeginners.com/blog/). Then I wanted to change some settings in my CSS file so I modified some lines. But when I ran the `python manage.py runserver` again(I ran on Windows), the changes did not take effect. The initial code of CSS is:

```
body {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}
```

I changed the padding resulting like this:

```
body {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}
```

When I ran the django server again, the new code was not taking effect. I checked the code with Chrome Dev Tools and found out the padding value was still 10px. I've been running the server again and again but with no change. Is there something I am missing with the settings?

Comment: Have you cleared your browser's cache ?

Comment: Unless you are specifically testing caching for other parts of your website, you should take a look at Dummy Cache for development: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/cache/#dummy-caching-for-development

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I oftenly have the same issue, you should delete the staticfiles directory.
Additionally, you should add "no cache" header to your HTML headers in your templates, at least for development.

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

In case of trouble, you can also force your browser to clear its cache.

In case you want to reconstruct the 'staticfiles' directory, you can run the command:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

You do not need to stop/relaunch the django server, it has no effect on the web files (HTML/JS/CSS).

Comment: I deleted the staticfile directory and made the directory again and it worked! The HTML thing is new for me. Thanks for the info and the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to collect the static files with this command, from the server instance :

```
./manage.py collectstatic
```

Then the updates in static files will be considered.

Comment: It returns me with this `>>> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.`

Comment: see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215581/unable-to-perform-collectstatic

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It is browser cache problem. You can solve it in many ways but what I found as the simplest way is to try out *Incognito* or *Private* mode of your browser. You will see every single change of *css* file instantly.