# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

hi I'm testing my `Django rest framework` project on a hosting server. when I open the my site domain my site is without any default django style. my admin panel is just `html` it doesn't have django admin panel style. I connected to the project on host and when i type the collect static command I have this error:

```
  django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.
```

this is the admin panel:

[image]

first page:
[image]
and this is my project settings.py:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tehran'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# ckeditor

CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/"
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to perform collectstatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215581/unable-to-perform-collectstatic)

Comment: I done this. the error fixed but still I have no style. just shown me html

Comment: Could you provide the files that are in the static folder for more context?