# Django static files not working on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

My django application is working well on local server. But, when I deploy it on Heroku, the static files are not being served (getting a 404 error). Please help!

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
       url(r'^$', 'product.views.home', name='home'),
       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

   )
if settings.DEBUG:
       urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
       urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

static files settings:

```
  TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
      os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
  )

  STATIC_URL = '/static/'

  MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

  MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "media")

  STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "static_root")

  STATICFILES_DIRS = (
      os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "static_dirs"),
  )
```

WSGI file -

```
  import os
  os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "acton.settings")

  from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
  application = get_wsgi_application()

  try:
      from dj_static import Cling
      application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())

  except:
      pass
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my setting for static files to deploy on Heroku.
Hope it will help :

> import os
>   BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(**file**))
>   STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
>   STATIC_URL ='/static/'
>   MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "media")
>   MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
>   STATICFILES_DIRS = (
>      os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
>   )

Comment: Still having the same issue!

Comment: can you tell if you are getting any error while deployment, on your terminal regarding running of python manage.py collectstatic command?

Comment: No, when I run 'heroku run python manage.py collectstatic' - I see no error, static files are collected. What weird is css files for admin on heroku is working. Its only the front end I am having issues.

Comment: change your STATIC_ROOT='staticfiles' to settings which i have written. There is no other way i see an issue in there. Since collectstatic collects all files in your 'staticfiles' folder in your project root. STATIC_URL is the path by which yo access them.

Comment: I deleted the Heroku app completely and re-deployed from scratch. Its working now! Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Your setting.py file is incorrectly configured.Static and media files should be

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: With my settings.py , the static files are working well on the development server. Its only on the Heroku production server I am having issue. Now, when I change the settings.py as per your recommendation, my static files are not working on development server!

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141315/django-static-files-on-heroku and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141315/django-static-files-on-heroku

Comment: I checked all these questions and tried their recommendation with no success. The static files are successfully collected on Heroku, but its not displaying.

Comment: What was the path that you were giving to your static files in your HTML templates?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that comes across this problem, for me it was that I was missing the whitenoise configuration from my wsgi.py file.

Specifically the following was missing from my `wsgi.py` file:

`from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)`

Docs are here: http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/