# Django static files - Changing URL

Tags: django, heroku, django-2.0

I'm a little confused with Django's static files.

I understand they are not served in development however in my production environment I have tried everything to change the URL for the files which are being server. It just doesnt make any sence to me.

Everything is still being served via `/static/` with my URL's even after changing `STATIC_URL`.

settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dsadsa')
STATIC_URL = '/ddd/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app/static'),
]
```

From those setting I expect all my static files to end up inside of a directory called `dsadsa` and server with a url `www.example.com/ddd/file.css` however this is just not the case they always get served via `www.example.com/static/file.css` from the directory `staticfiles`.

I'm running this project in Heroku with no `Debug = False`

Can anyone please help me understand what on earth I'm missing here?

Update:

I'm using `{% load static %}` within the templates.

Example template usage:

```
<img alt="background" src="{% static "img/inner-6.jpg" %}" />
```

Comment: Show an example of the template, please.

Comment: Did you restart the server, and *hard* refreshed the page?

Comment: Template usage added. Yes restart of Dynos makes no difference.

Comment: Note: I have just found this so I'm trying to implement. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141315/django-static-files-on-heroku

Comment: Update: That did not work. Still always served from `/static/` what am I missing?

Comment: It's weird. Is there other static settings?

Comment: @seuling I have searched the whole project. No other static settings anywhere. Nothing I do will change the `/static/` URL in the references in the HTML. Ever :S

Comment: It should change. I guess it's not your setting's problem. What is your environment? Can you runserver in your localhost?

Comment: I can runserver in my local environment. The project is on Heroku. Nothin I do changes the public facing URI. :S I have given up for now,

Comment: For the sake of documenting another source of error, at least when not deploying to heroku but hosting yourself (e.g. uWSGI-NGINX):

Simply adding a subdirectory (e.g. `/mydjangoapp` as in `www.mydomain.com/mydjangoapp`) to FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME, STATIC_URL, STATIC_FILES_URL, ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX,... has not gained anything for me as well. Finally I found removing the left-over `django_heroku.settings(locals())`-line finally provided the subdirectory-prefix in the static-file links

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for...maybe

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ddd')
STATIC_URL = '/ddd/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR,]
```

The above will link `{% load staticfiles %}` in your `base.html` to the static folder which houses `img/css/etc.`

This will point all references to `{% load staticfiles %}` to the static folder under your base project.

Comment: I will give this a try. Why `{% load staticfiles %}` and not `{% load static %}` - Also this will fail to collect my static files in the app directory as its not stated in `STATICFILES_DIRS`?

Comment: This has also made no difference what so ever.

Comment: Did you run "python manage.py collectstatic".  That will put all the contents of your static files into the static root.  It should be noted that the STATIC_ROOT should be a new file under the root of your project, same level as the original 'static' folder.