# No css styles on Django web-app deployed on heroku

Tags: python, css, django, heroku, web-applications

I have created a simple web-app using django when i run it on my localhost it works fine. But after I deployed it to heroku the admin page has no css

my `setting.py` file has configuration

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

When I visit my site deployed on heroku the admin page looks like this (ie, no css)
[image: heroku site error screenshot]

And on my localhost it lookscompletely fine

[image: same website on localhost]

i also ran `python manage.py collectstatic` command
In static folder all css are present but when ran on heroku they are not loaded

Edit - 
I have not added any css
They are the css files provided by django by default

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django static files on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141315/django-static-files-on-heroku) There's also this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

Comment: Thanks man. The article from heroku helped me. I installed whitenoise middleware and all files were loaded.