# Django images in static folder can not show on Heroku project

Tags: django, image, heroku, static

I deployed my app on Heroku.

But the images in my static folder won't show up.

---

### In my local environment, here is the screenshot

[image]

### But on the project, the images fails to load

[image]

---

### Here are code in multiple related files.

#### settings.py

```py
from pathlib import Path
import os


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # additional django
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',

    'article',
    'taggit',
    'crispy_forms',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'blog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'article.context_processors.common_context'
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'blog.wsgi.application'

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

SITE_ID = 1


if os.environ.get('DJANGO_PRODUCTION'):

    import dj_database_url

    DATABASES = {
        'default': dj_database_url.config(),
    }
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

    # Allow all host headers.
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
        'ycy-blog.herokuapp.com',
        'www.ycyangtw.com',
    ]

    # Turn off DEBUG mode.
    DEBUG = (os.environ.get('DEBUG_VALUE') == 'True')
```

### urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin, sitemaps
from django.urls import path
from django.urls.conf import include
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from article.sitemaps import PostSitemap

sitemaps = {
    'posts': PostSitemap,
}


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin_page/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('article.urls', namespace='article')),


    path(
        'sitemap.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps},
        name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'
    ),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) \
    + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

### test_static.html

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        hello
    </h1>
    <img src="{% static 'article/cover/fed-fund-rate_cover.jpg' %}">
</body>
</html>
```

---

I have been through lots of similar questions on stackoverflow,

but still can not solve

What is exactly happend?

thanks for help

Comment: Did you create `collectstaticfiles` and configured collectstatic files in `settings.py`?

Comment: Hi, mhhabib. Do you mean `STATIC_ROOT`  or something else?  `STATIC_ROOT` is in `settings.py` already.

Comment: Before deploying to Heroku your static file should be collected like to staticfiles `python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: Just tried `python manage.py collectstatic` and push again, still doesn't work :( . Tks

Answer (score 0):

Have you collected the static files?

Try running:

```
heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --dry-run --noinput
```

Comment: Hi Marmik. Just tried, but still doesn't work. Tks.

Comment: Points need to be check, install whitenoise, configure STATIC_ROOT correctly, and don't forget to add middleware `'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware'`, Thank you.

Comment: Install whitelnoise, configure `STATIC_ROOT` and add middleware were all done, btw, `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')` is correct for heroku right?

Comment: actually there is some cache. try checking this [feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141315/django-static-files-on-heroku)

Comment: tks, I am sure the images have been uploaded successfully, it shows  message during push to Heroku. Or do you think I set the wrong path?

Answer (score 0):

in your urls.py use this

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

instead of

```
+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) \
    + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

then run py manage.py collectstatic and then push to heroku master

Comment: Hi, Shreyash. I tried both earlier. They showed the same result. The problem has been solved. Tks.

Answer (score 0):

Brief Summary.

Due to the name of the folder of images is contained in `.gitignore` file which is `cover` and I didn't notice that. Those files were not been upload actually.

I use `heroku run bash` to check my project structure then find out the `cover` folder won't show up in any way. Then I check `.gitignore` to figure out what exactly happened.

Tks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to add `STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / "static"]` to your settings.py