# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'regex' django 1.9

Tags: python, django, windows, django-1.9

I am working with django 1.9 and I am currently coding - in Windows Command Prompt - `python manage.py makemigrations` and the error:

***AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'regex'***

I have tried coding:

```
url(r'^$', 'firstsite.module.views.start', name="home"),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
url(r'^signup/$', 'exam.views.signup', name='signup'),
url(r'^signup/submit/$', 'exam.views.signup_submit', name='signup_submit')
```

in urls.py and the error is keeps coming up.

This is my first time coding in django, so my expertise is very limited. Thank you in advance.

This is the whole urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
import django
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  # Examples:
  # url(r'^$', 'firstsite.views.home', name='home'),
  # url(r'^firstsite/', include('firstsite.foo.urls')),

  # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
  # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

  # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
  #url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

  django.conf.urls.handler400,

  url(r'^$', 'firstsite.module.views.start', name="home"),
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
  url(r'^signup/$', 'exam.views.signup', name='signup'),
  url(r'^signup/submit/$', 'exam.views.signup_submit', name='signup_submit'),
  )
```

Comment: Can you show full traceback, then we can help you?

Comment: Please show the whole urls.py as well. The problem could be the way you are defining `urlpatterns`, not in an individual `url()`.

Comment: Do you _really_ have this `django.conf.urls.handler400` line in the middle of your urls ??? If yes remove it, a `view` is not an `url`...

Comment: Also note you'll get a `RemovedInDjango110Warning: Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10 (got django.contrib.auth.views.login). Pass the callable instead.
  url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name="login")`. Use `from django.contrib import auth` and `auth.views.login` instead.

Answer (score 11):

Also make sure to remove the beginning empty url pattern--can be overlooked when migrating your urls.

```
urlpatterns = ['', # <== this blank element ('') produces the error.
    ...
]
```

### tl;dr

For the curious, I found this out by adding a warning to the `check_pattern_startswith_slash` method in the `django.core.checks.urls` module:

```
def check_pattern_startswith_slash(pattern):
    """
    Check that the pattern does not begin with a forward slash.
    """
    if not hasattr(pattern, 'regex'):
        warning = Warning(
            "Invalid pattern '%s'" % pattern,
            id="urls.W002",
        )
        return [warning]
```

And, sure enough, I got a bunch of warnings like this:

```
?: (urls.W002) Invalid pattern ''
```

Comment: Django 1.10 will check for invalid objects in `urlpatterns`, and display a warning if it finds any. See [ticket 26440](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26440). Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 10):

Firstly, remove the `django.conf.urls.handler400` from the middle of the urlpatterns. It doesn't belong there, and is the cause of the error.

Once the error has been fixed, you can make a couple of changes to update your code for Django 1.8+

1. Change `urlpatterns` to a list, instead of using `patterns()`
2. Import the views (or view modules), instead of using strings in your `urls()`
3. You are using the same regex for the `start` and `login` views. This means you won't be able to reach the login views. One fix would be to change the regex for the login view to something like `^login/$`

Putting that together, you get something like:

```
from firstsite.module.views import start
from exam import views as exam_views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', start, name="home"),
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
  url(r'^signup/$', exam_views.signup, name='signup'),
  url(r'^signup/submit/$', exam_views.signup_submit, name='signup_submit'),
]
```

Comment: OP might want to fix the identical root patterns, as well.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman, I hadn't spotted that. I've updated the answer.

Comment: You had `'exam.views.signup'` in your question, so you should have an app `exam` in your project, which contains an `__init__.py` file. Do you? For us to be able to help you, you might need to update your question to include the file layout of your project.

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair for the help. However what does firstsite.module mean? An error keeps coming up no module named 'firstsite.module'.

Comment: Again, this is based on the urls.py in your question. You had `'firstsite.module.views.start'`, which suggests that you have a `views.py` inside the `firstsite/module` directory.

Answer (score 2):

**Remove the beginning empty `Url` patterns** and 
also remove

```
django.conf.urls.handler400,
```

from your `urls.py` this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**For Django 2**

```
from django.urls.resolvers import get_resolver, URLPattern, URLResolver

urls = get_resolver()

def if_none(value):
    if value:
        return value
    return ''

def print_urls(urls, parent_pattern=None):
    for url in urls.url_patterns:
        if isinstance(url, URLResolver):
            print_urls(url, if_none(parent_pattern) + if_none(str(url.pattern)))
        elif isinstance(url, URLPattern):
            print(f"{url} ({url.lookup_str})")
            print('----')
print_urls(urls)
```