# How to render a Matplotlib plot in a Django web application?

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I'm reading the book [Matplotlib for Python Developers](https://github.com/pmalonis/plotting-programs/blob/master/Matplotlib%20for%20Python%20Developers%20(2009).pdf) but am struggling to follow the example in the section "Matplotlib in a Django application" in chapter 8.

So far, I've issued the command

```
django-admin startproject mpldjango
```

and, in the `mpldjango` directory,

```
python manage.py startapp mpl
```

As per the example, in `mpldjango/mpl` I've made the `views.py` as follows:

```
import django
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np

def mplimage(request):
    fig = Figure()
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    x = np.arange(-2,1.5,.01)
    y = np.sin(np.exp(2*x))
    ax.plot(x, y)
    response=django.http.HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
    canvas.print_png(response)
    return response
```

Next, the book says that the `mpldjango/urls.py` should have this line added to it:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
       (r'mplimage.png', 'mpl.views.mplimage'),
)
```

However, I don't see how this would work since in the 'default' `urls.py`, `urlpatterns` is a lits of `django.conf.urls.url` objects:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

and there is no `patterns` constructor defined. Perhaps this book (which is from 2009) is referring to a legacy Django API? If so, how would I modify this code to make it work? (That is, after `python manage.py runserver` I should be able to browse to `localhost:8000/mplimage.png` and see an image of a chirped sinusoid).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [cannot import name patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074955/cannot-import-name-patterns) this is indeed a legacy interface of Django. I 'updated' it by making `mpldjango/urls.py` as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
import mpl.views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'mplimage.png', mpl.views.mplimage),
]
```

Now if I browse to http://localhost:8000/mplimage.png I see the plot as desired:

[image]