# Django - how to best integrate matplotlib

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I am trying to display a graph using matplotlib and django. I've read quite a lot of questions on stack but still don't understand what the best way is to use matplotlib in Django.

SITUATION:

I have a model that has a bunch of data in. In views.py I then have a simple form that captures some data and queries the model and returns a subset of the data. Here is the relevant views.py section:

```
def getinput(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         form = get_data(request.POST)

         if form.is_valid():
             down = form.cleaned_data['get_down']
             ytg = form.cleaned_data['get_ytg']
             yfog = form.cleaned_data['get_yfog']
             map_data = next_play.objects.filter(last_dwn__exact=down, last_yfog__exact=yfog, last_ytg__exact=ytg)
             context = {'form': form, 'query_data': map_data}
             return render(request, 'play_outcomes/output.html', context)
     else:
         form = get_data()


     return render(request, 'play_outcomes/getinput.html', {'form': form})
```

When I got to `play_outcomes/getinput` and enter `dwn ytg yfog` the template then outputs a whole ton of data.

It is this data I want to plot i.e., the data in `map_data`.

QUESTION:

How do I integrate matplotlib into this? Do I integrate the `matplotlib` code in views.py, should I set it up in a separate python module? Presumably I need to create a png file and then show that?

Comment: save the plot as an image and then display in the html
?

Comment: but do i do this in views.py or should I do it in a separate python file

Comment: Personally, I would execute it in another file but there is nothing to stop you doing it in views,py.. It might just get a little crowded in the code. Especially if you start bigger, more detailed plots..

Comment: Have a look here.. I think this question will answer your problem!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45460145/how-to-render-a-matplotlib-plot-in-a-django-web-application

Comment: great - thanks johnashu

Comment: I am interested how you solve this problem.. its something I have thought about be not done..  Please answer your own question with the correct code or let us know if you get stuck :)  Good Luck!

Comment: Will do - will look at it this evening and revert

Answer (score 2):

A figure is a view, so view is a good place. On the other hand, matplot lib could be verbose, and you would like to set various constants, so that every figure look like with similar style.  For such reason I would recommend to move all figure code in a new file.

In general, I avoid creating graphs in Django. Just a "off-line" batch, to create some statistic graphs, or I would try to use d3.js, to offload figure generation to clients (but so they receive the dataset).  There are also some hybrid variants, which I never tried, e.g. http://subsetlab.com/super-fund-performance-and-fees.html (check the second part: "how to do it").