# How to modifying url.py to run in latest django version?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _ from django.contrib import admin admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')), )

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    (_(r'^dual-lang/'), include('duallang.urls')),
    (r'^', include('home.urls')), )

from django.conf import settings

if 'rosetta' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^rosetta/', include('rosetta.urls')),
    )
```

> Getting ImportError: cannot import name 'patterns' from
>   'django.conf.urls'

Comment: please explain old django version

Comment: django old version=1.8 [link] (' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074955/cannot-import-name-patterns') ** cannot import name patterns**

Comment: I doesn't want to use Django-Guardian to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you must convert pattern to list, url can be conveted to path or re_path like this:

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n'))
]
```

i18n_pattern can be used like this:

```
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
   path('', include('home.urls'))
)
```

Comment: (_(r'^dual-lang/'), include('duallang.urls')),

Comment: pass _ to string argument of `path`