# import name patterns issue with django

Tags: django, server, mod-wsgi

After digging I cannot manage to understand what happened with our server. I got this error when loading the web.

It was working and anyone touch anything. I have changed the ownership of the application.txt because this error.
[Wed Dec 16 04:38:12.059839 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 12343:tid 140072894818048] [remote xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx] ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/yhmp-app/YHMP/eamena/logs/application.txt'

After this it is showing up the next error in the browser:[image]

and all this is coming form the error.log when trying to access:

```
ed Dec 16 13:05:46.856703 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 14049:tid 140483607127808] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Wed Dec 16 13:05:46.856746 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 14049:tid 140483607127808] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client ] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Wed Dec 16 13:05:46.856782 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 14049:tid 140483607127808] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client :56384] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Wed Dec 16 13:05:46.856787 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 14049:tid 140483607127808] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client :56384] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857793 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456] Internal Server Error: /
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857809 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857814 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857817 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]     response = get_response(request)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857821 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 244, in _legacy_get_response
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857824 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]     response = middleware_method(request)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857828 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/locale.py", line 24, in process_request
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857831 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]     i18n_patterns_used, prefixed_default_language = is_language_prefix_patterns_used(urlconf)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857834 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 100, in wrapper
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857838 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]     result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857841 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/i18n.py", line 29, in is_language_prefix_patterns_used
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857844 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]     for url_pattern in get_resolver(urlconf).url_patterns:
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857847 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857857 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857861 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 407, in url_patterns
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857865 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857868 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857871 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857874 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 400, in urlconf_module
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857877 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857880 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857883 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]     __import__(name)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857886 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/YHMP/eamena/urls.py", line 19, in <module>
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857889 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]     from arches import urls as arches_urls
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857892 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/arches/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857895 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]     from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.857898 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456] ImportError: cannot import name patterns
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.928281 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456] Internal Server Error: /
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.928306 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.928310 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 131, in get_response
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.928313 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]     response = middleware_method(request, response)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.928316 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/locale.py", line 36, in process_response
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.928319 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]     i18n_patterns_used, prefixed_default_language = is_language_prefix_patterns_used(urlconf)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.928323 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 100, in wrapper
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.928326 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]     result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.928329 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/i18n.py", line 29, in is_language_prefix_patterns_used
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.928332 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]     for url_pattern in get_resolver(urlconf).url_patterns:
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.928335 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.928338 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.928341 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 407, in url_patterns
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.928354 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.928357 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.928360 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.928363 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 400, in urlconf_module
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.928366 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.928369 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.928372 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]     __import__(name)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.928375 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/YHMP/eamena/urls.py", line 19, in <module>
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.928378 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]     from arches import urls as arches_urls
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.928381 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/arches/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.928384 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456]     from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:46.928387 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483690739456] ImportError: cannot import name patterns
[Wed Dec 16 13:05:47.258838 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 14048:tid 140483573556992] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client :56386] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://database.yhmp.online/
[Wed Dec 16 13:05:47.258876 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 14048:tid 140483573556992] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client :56386] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://database.yhmp.online/
[Wed Dec 16 13:05:47.258911 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 14048:tid 140483573556992] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client :56386] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://database.yhmp.online/
[Wed Dec 16 13:05:47.258915 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 14048:tid 140483573556992] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client :56386] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://database.yhmp.online/
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259857 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640] Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259871 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259875 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259878 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]     response = get_response(request)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259881 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 244, in _legacy_get_response
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259885 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]     response = middleware_method(request)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259888 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/locale.py", line 24, in process_request
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259892 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]     i18n_patterns_used, prefixed_default_language = is_language_prefix_patterns_used(urlconf)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259895 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 100, in wrapper
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259909 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]     result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259912 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/i18n.py", line 29, in is_language_prefix_patterns_used
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259916 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]     for url_pattern in get_resolver(urlconf).url_patterns:
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259919 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259922 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259925 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 407, in url_patterns
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259928 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259931 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259934 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259937 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 400, in urlconf_module
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259940 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259943 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259946 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]     __import__(name)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259948 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/YHMP/eamena/urls.py", line 19, in <module>
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259951 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]     from arches import urls as arches_urls
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259954 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/arches/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259957 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]     from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.259960 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640] ImportError: cannot import name patterns
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.323245 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640] Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.323268 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.323271 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 131, in get_response
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.323275 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]     response = middleware_method(request, response)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.323278 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/locale.py", line 36, in process_response
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.323281 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]     i18n_patterns_used, prefixed_default_language = is_language_prefix_patterns_used(urlconf)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.323284 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 100, in wrapper
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.323287 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]     result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.323290 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/i18n.py", line 29, in is_language_prefix_patterns_used
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.323302 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]     for url_pattern in get_resolver(urlconf).url_patterns:
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.323306 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.323309 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.323312 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 407, in url_patterns
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.323315 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.323318 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.323321 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.323324 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 400, in urlconf_module
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.323327 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.323329 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.323332 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]     __import__(name)
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.323335 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/YHMP/eamena/urls.py", line 19, in <module>
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.323338 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]     from arches import urls as arches_urls
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.323341 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]   File "/opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/arches/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.323344 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640]     from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
[Wed Dec 16 07:05:47.323347 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14047:tid 140483741136640] ImportError: cannot import name patterns
```

Sorry for the long log copy and paste, do someone have an idea about what can happened to that? We work within the same server but supposedly anyone touch nothing so it is being very difficult to find where to look for.
in addition this is the file pointed in the Exception Location: /opt/yhmp-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/arches/urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls.i18n import patterns

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

uuid_regex = '[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}'

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'arches.app.views.main.index'),
    url(r'^index.htm', 'arches.app.views.main.index', name='home'),
    url(r'^auth/', 'arches.app.views.main.auth', name='auth'),
    url(r'^rdm/(?P<conceptid>%s|())$' % uuid_regex , 'arches.app.views.concept.rdm', name='rdm'),
    url(r'^map', 'arches.app.views.map.get_page', name="map"),
    url(r'^geocoder', 'arches.app.views.search.geocode', name="geocoder"),
    
    url(r'^entities/(?P<entityid>%s)$' % uuid_regex , 'arches.app.views.entity.Entities'),
    url(r'^entityTypes/(?P<entitytypeid>.*)$', 'arches.app.views.entity.EntityTypes'),
    url(r'^concepts/(?P<conceptid>%s)/manage_parents/$' % uuid_regex, 'arches.app.views.concept.manage_parents', name="concept_manage_parents"),        
    url(r'^concepts/(?P<conceptid>%s)/confirm_delete/$' % uuid_regex, 'arches.app.views.concept.confirm_delete', name="confirm_delete"),     
    url(r'^concepts/(?P<conceptid>%s|())$' % uuid_regex , 'arches.app.views.concept.concept', name="concept"),
    url(r'^concepts/tree$', 'arches.app.views.concept.concept_tree', name="concept_tree"),      
    url(r'^concepts/search$', 'arches.app.views.concept.search', name="concept_search"),
    url(r'^concepts/(?P<conceptid>%s)/from_sparql_endpoint$' % uuid_regex, 'arches.app.views.concept.add_concepts_from_sparql_endpoint', name="from_sparql_endpoint"),
    url(r'^concepts/search_sparql_endpoint$', 'arches.app.views.concept.search_sparql_endpoint_for_concepts', name="search_sparql_endpoint"),
    url(r'^search$', 'arches.app.views.search.home_page', name="search_home"),
    url(r'^search/terms$', 'arches.app.views.search.search_terms', name="search_terms"),
    url(r'^search/resources$', 'arches.app.views.search.search_results', name="search_results"),
    url(r'^buffer/$', 'arches.app.views.search.buffer', name="buffer"),
    url(r'^resources/(?P<resourcetypeid>[0-9a-zA-Z_.]*)/(?P<form_id>[a-zA-Z_-]*)/(?P<resourceid>%s|())$' % uuid_regex, 'arches.app.views.resources.resource_manager', name="resource_manager"),
    url(r'^resources/related/(?P<resourceid>%s|())$' % uuid_regex, 'arches.app.views.resources.related_resources', name="related_resources"),
    url(r'^resources/history/(?P<resourceid>%s|())$' % uuid_regex, 'arches.app.views.resources.edit_history', name="edit_history"),
    url(r'^resources/layers/(?P<entitytypeid>.*)$', 'arches.app.views.resources.map_layers', name="map_layers"),
    url(r'^resources/markers/(?P<entitytypeid>.*)$', 'arches.app.views.resources.map_layers', {'get_centroids':True}, name="map_markers"),
    url(r'^reports/(?P<resourceid>%s)$' % uuid_regex , 'arches.app.views.resources.report', name='report'),
    url(r'^get_admin_areas','arches.app.views.resources.get_admin_areas', name='get_admin_areas'),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # enables language change via form
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()

if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

After pip freeze in the env mode i get the following details in case they are relevant to  solve the issue:

```
appdirs==1.4.4
arches==3.1.2
arches-hip==1.0.4
configparser==4.0.2
contextlib2==0.6.0.post1
distlib==0.3.1
Django==1.7.11
elasticsearch==1.9.0
filelock==3.0.12
importlib-metadata==2.1.1
importlib-resources==3.3.0
isodate==0.6.0
packaging==20.8
pathlib2==2.3.5
Pillow==2.4.0
pluggy==0.13.1
psycopg2==2.5.4
py==1.10.0
pycryptodome==3.8.1
pyparsing==2.4.0
pyshp==2.1.0
pytz==2020.4
PyYAML==5.1
rdflib==4.2.2
scandir==1.10.0
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.15.0
SPARQLWrapper==1.8.4
toml==0.10.2
tox==3.20.1
typing==3.7.4.3
unicodecsv==0.14.1
urllib3==1.25.2
virtualenv==20.2.2
xlrd==0.9.0
zipp==1.2.0
```

Also after change the version of django it appear thsi other error not idea if it is realted:

[image]

I would really appreciate your expertise with this and if you can point me in some direction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: which version of django do you use ?

Comment: from the browser error page seems to be 1.11.29.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was the servers version of django upgraded? `patterns` was deprecated in 1.10

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38799716/1464664

current implementations looks like this

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', views.index, name='main-view'),
    path('bio/<username>/', views.bio, name='bio'),
    path('articles/<slug:title>/', views.article, name='article-detail'),
    path('articles/<slug:title>/<int:section>/', views.section, name='article-section'),
    path('weblog/', include('blog.urls')),
    ...
]
```

*edit

To install an older version of django on the server.

```
pip install "django==1.10.*"

 Collecting django==1.10.*
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/9f/2c20639ac635a83123ddffd91ba15001cb0d04e74fbb08f31fb57e490dab/Django-1.10.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.8MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 6.8MB 17.2MB/s 
Installing collected packages: django
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10.8.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

WARNING: You are using pip version 19.1.1, however version 20.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: yes i have been looking to this at this moment. It is suppose anyone did it but everything point to this. There is a ny chance to bring it back to oldest versions?

Comment: Added to the answer, hope that helps :)

Comment: thanks so to match with the patterns issue I should pip install "django==1.10" correct?  thanks!

Comment: `pip install "django==1.10.*"` Yes that shuold do it for you. That last `*` is important.

Comment: i have updated the question to included what i get when i pip install "django==1.10.*" should i use the env mode?

Comment: gcj, Yes. start the env, eg. `source PATH_TO_ENV/bin/activate` .   Verify the version issue w/ `pip freeze`

Comment: Thanks I used to django 1.8.19 but now is appearing another error ProgrammingError at /
relation "d_languages" does not exist
LINE 1: ...s"."languagename", "d_languages"."isdefault" FROM "d_languag

Comment: Looks like migrations need to be run, did other libs change also - this is probably a different question.

Comment: maybe it was modify urls.py? .... import patterns there is a way to see how should look for the version of django isntalled

Comment: The `pip freeze` command will list the versions and libraries installed